# RSS Feed MySQL - Not displaying lowest MYSQL ID on GROUP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a RSS Script and have some Problem showing the lowest ID of nNr to show cPath (image)

MySQL Database seems like here

```
tartikel
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
| kArtikel | cName |  cKurzBeschreibung  | dErstellt  | cSeo  |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
|   560    | 12345 |   Short Description | 2014-03-25 | 12345 |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+
|   561    | ABCDE |   Short Description | 2014-03-25 | abcde |
+----------+-------+---------------------+------------+-------+

tartikelpict
+--------------+--------------+-------+
| kartikelpict |     cPfad    |  nNr  |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
|     560      | picture4.jpg |   4   |
|     560      | picture3.jpg |   3   |
|     560      | picture2.jpg |   2   |
|     560      | picture.jpg  |   1   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
|     561      | picture4.jpg |   4   |
|     561      | picture3.jpg |   3   |
|     561      | picture2.jpg |   2   |
|     561      | picture.jpg  |   1   |
+--------------+--------------+-------+
```

My PHP Code

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT 
    p1.kArtikel, 
    p1.cName, 
    p1.cKurzBeschreibung, 
    p1.dLetzteAktualisierung, 
    p1.dErstellt, 
    p1.cSeo,
    p2.kartikelpict,
    p2.nNr,
    p2.cPfad

    FROM tartikel AS p1

    JOIN tartikelpict AS p2 

    ON (p1.kArtikel = p2.kartikelpict)

    JOIN (SELECT kartikelpict ,MIN(nNr) nNr FROM tartikelpict GROUP BY kartikelpict ) p3

    ON(p2.kartikelpict = p3.kartikelpict AND p2.nNr = p3.nNr)

    ORDER BY p1.kArtikel 

    DESC LIMIT 50', $connection);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $cName = $row['cName']; 
    $cKurzBeschreibung = $row['cKurzBeschreibung']; 
    $dLetzteAktualisierung = $row['dLetzteAktualisierung'];
    $dErstellt = $row['dErstellt'];
    $cSeo = $row['cSeo']; 
    $date = strtotime($row['dErstellt']);
    $pubdate = date(r, $date);
    $id = $row['kArtikel'];
    $nNr = $row['nNr'];
    $cPfad = $row['cPfad'];

echo "\t\t" . '<enclosure url="'.$cPath.'" type="image/jpeg" />' . "\n";
```

The Result (it should be only the lowest)

```
<enclosure url="4" />
<enclosure url="3" />
<enclosure url="2" />
<enclosure url="1" />
```

I think I can't build the logic to get the right element. I have to get the ID of nNr and than select cPfad right? What am I doing wrong?

The SQL and Table seems to be OK after tested [@sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0facd/1) [(thx to Khalid)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/853360/m-khalid-junaid). Any idea what is wrong on my Code?

Comment: What's the question? The query is returning the correct data. What's wrong with the output of your script?

Comment: As described above "have some Problem getting the lowest ID of nNr to show cPath". I want to show from the lowest nNr the cPath but my Script takes 4, 3, 2, 1. Not the lowest one.

Comment: The query only returns `nNr = 1`, I don't see any way that the script could be showing anything other than what the query returns.

Comment: You're not echoing any of the variables you set from `$row`. You're echoing `$cPath`, but you never set it.

Comment: Check here the complete script and at the end the result http://pastebin.com/mCGUN48V